# Is it okay to install a sediment filter backward in a reverse osmosis system?

Tags: water-purification

I just had my reverse osmosis system serviced. The technician said that the sediment filter had some problem in passing water. The water pressure was low in the correct (or marked) water flow direction. He tried to clean it and then placed it back in the reverse direction. He said that it is okay to have it in reverse direction as it will serve it purpose, but looking at the videos of whats inside a sediment filter, I think this is not the right way.

Can some please tell if this is okay or should I get it reverted?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say conclusively without knowing what brand or type filter it is, but chances are it's just a fine screen. The concern would be that the cavity intended to collect sediment may not exist on the downstream side. If that's the case it will clog sooner. Otherwise it should serve the function just fine.

Post brand and model information or a photo in your question if you'd like more specific advice.